# Regex pattern format for austrian numbers

Tags: regex, pcre2

Here is what i have right now.

```
(\d{4,12}\/*(\+43)* *(\([0-9]+\))*([ ]*(-|–)*[ ]*[0-9]+))
```

or

```
([\/ \-\d]*)
```

Allowed:

```
03852 4637
03852 463728
03852/4637
038524637
03852463728
03852/463728
004338524637
+4338524637
00433852463728
+433852463728
00433852/4637
+4303852/4637
00433852/463728
+433852/463728

01 23457
0123457
01/23457
0043123457

+43 662 8180-0
0662 8180-0
0662 81800
066281800
0662 8180
06628180
0043662 818
00436628180
+43662 8180
```

Not Allowed:

```
122
133
144
121
911
112
110
```

Phone Number can be in between sentences and should match as "Match 1"

`([\/ \-\d]*)`

Matches with the allowed numbers but ignores the "+"

Comment: Try `^(?!\d{1,6}$)(?:(?:\+43|00) ?)?\d+(?:[ \/–-]\d+)*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works great thank you, what if there are letters after the number that shouldn't match

Example: +43662 8180zzz

Comment: Figured it out, thanks for your help <3

Comment: Well, not sure it works for you in full, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGh8mj/1). Why do you need to match `0385246372802`, `03852/4637281`, `00433637` and `+433852463799`? If you want to match them, please remove them from "Not allowed" section.

Comment: I meant i want to only match numbers that start with 0/00/+43. it matches these numbers but it shouldnt match anything that starts different, sorry for the wrong description

Comment: Then use the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?!\d{1,6}$)(?:(?:\+43|00?) ?)\d+(?:[ \/–-]\d+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WGh8mj/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\d{1,6}$)` - the string cannot consist of just one to six digits
- `(?:(?:\+43|00?) ?)` - a sequence of `+43`, `00` or `0` and then an optional space
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[ \/–-]\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a space/slash, em-dash or hyphen and then one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.